# how to add a new field in Asp.net membership?

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a "DisplayName" property to the membership class different from userName. I am not using the Profiles, can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. That is what profiles are for.

Answer (score 1):

Most customizations are provided to add custom logic for accessing a custom database, etc.  The membership provider wasn't necessarily meant for adding fields, though it's possible, but not worth the effort.  You'd have to write a custom provider, customize all of the membership controls (if you use them).  The Membership.CreateUser doesn't accept custom params, so you'd have to figure out a way to work around that, maybe by going directly to the provider as in ((MyProvider)Membership.Provider).CreateUser(myCustomUserObject); just to get it to work...